# RemoveClass and AddClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think this may be because these elements didn't originally have the `DOM` element. I have tried using events and then a propagation tool, but it's still not working :(

I want it so that when you click one of the items, it removes the underline from all items, and then adds it to the item that you just clicked, but in this case it keeps it underlined. To test just use the fiddle link and click on the first **"A"**, and then the second bigger **"A"**

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/B9VAA/22/))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li.big").on("click", function(e) {
    $("li>a.underline").removeClass("underline");
    $("li.big").addClass("underline");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $("li.default").on("click", function(e) {
    $("li>a.underline").removeClass("underline");
    $("li.default").addClass("underline");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <div class="raisetext">Raise Text:</div>
  </li>
  <li class="default"><a href="#" class="underline">A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="big"><a href="#" style="font-size: 20px;">A</a>
  </li>
  <li class="bigger"><a href="#" style="font-size: 26px;">A</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your fiddle does not have `A's`

Comment: Your fiddle is completely out of sync with your question's code.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/B9VAA/23/

Comment: let me know if it works for you

Comment: yes that is the correct one.

Comment: @Sushil Sadly, that's not what I was looking for :(

Answer (score 0):

To add to Sushils answer, it sounded like the anchors were appended. So, just in case the anchor tags were dynamically appended to the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").on("click","a", function() {
    $("li > a").removeClass("underline");
    $(this).addClass("underline");
  });
});
```

Comment: the problem is I need to use li.big, and not just "li" because I need to do further edits and actions based on what link was exactly clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `$('a').on('click', function(){` instead of the `li.big` and `li.default` since they're all links.

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').on('click', function(){
        $('a').removeClass('underline');
        $(this).addClass('underline');
    });
});
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B9VAA/23/)**

note: this will apply to all the links on the page. if you don't wan't it to apply to all the links, then you can use a class.

Comment: the problem is I need to use li.big, and not just "a" because I need to do further edits and actions based on what link was exactly clicked.